# Chrome Dev Tools - Is there a way to show matching tag in DOM when you hover over its counterpart?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

In Firefox Inspector, if you hover over a `<div>` in the DOM, the corresponding `</div>` gets highlighted too.  Great!

How can you do something similar in Chrome Dev tools?  I can't seem to find how to find the counterpart tag.  I find myself visually trying to eye where the matching tag is, or try to move my mouse straight up and down to find it... seems there is a better way.

Even IE dev tools shows a vertical line connecting the opening and closing tags.

It's hard for me to believe that Chrome doesn't have a similar method for finding this.  Any ideas?

Comment: This might not help depending on why you are looking for the `</div>` tag, but I used the left and right arrow keys to collapse and expand the element to get an idea of what's part of it and what isn't.

Answer (score 1):

This just automagically showed up as a new feature in Chrome a couple days ago.. (with the vertical line style, like IE dev tools)  Thank you Chrome devs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if DevTools has the exact functionality you're looking for, but:

Open up your file in the **Sources** panel, double-click on a tag to highlight its text, and all matching instances of that text are outlined.

[image: highlighted word in chrome devtools sources panel]

If you select a tag in the **Elements** panel and press left and right arrows, you can expand / collapse all children of the selected tag.

And, of course, if you edit a tag in the **Elements** panel, the closing tag is automatically updated, too.