# Increase the width of the Search box on Elements tab in Google Developer Tools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Anyone know how to increase the width of the Search box on Elements tab in Google Developer Tools?  Right now it's only ~200px wide.. that makes it hard to see any CSS selector or Xpath locator that's more than ~25 characters long.
[Screenshot Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiAlT.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can't change this without a custom theme. Which shouldn't be needed just for this. I've opened [a bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=620048) for the team to know I'm going to patch this to make the input take as much width is available.

Comment: Sweet!  I suppose I'll just magically see the improvement show up some day... just like [this question/request I had](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36343327/chrome-dev-tools-is-there-a-way-to-show-matching-tag-in-dom-when-you-hover-ove) just seemed to show up a few days ago.

Comment: Hi Johnathan, any progress on this?  The ticket is still open.

Comment: Oh yea. It's kinda complicated given the current layout is table based simply resizing it (or modding it to be flex) completely breaks the layout. Toyed with it a bit and haven't swung back around to look at that. Maybe I'll do that later today if I have some free time.